# .net7 maui. Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.xxx.appName. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, .net-7.0

I'm trying to use the Plugin.Firebase notification service. I tried to follow the Plugin.Firebase documentation from github, but I get an initialization error. Also, I tried to follow other tutorials, but I get the same problem.

[error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42vWX.png)

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
        private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebaseServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events => {
#if IOS
                events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                    CrossFirebase.Initialize(CreateCrossFirebaseSettings());
                    return false;
                }));
#elif ANDROID

                events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, _) => {
                    CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity, CreateCrossFirebaseSettings());
                }));

#endif
            });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => CrossFirebaseAuth.Current);
            return builder;
        }

        private static CrossFirebaseSettings CreateCrossFirebaseSettings()
        {
            return new CrossFirebaseSettings(isCloudMessagingEnabled: true);
        }
```

Also, I have a problem with choosing a build action for google-services.json. VS 2022 does not come with the GoogleServicesJson option, so I added this to MyProject.csproj manually. I'm not sure if this will work the same as if I selected build action in the google-services.json properties.
**MyProject.csproj**

```
 <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android33.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity">
      <Version>1.8.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.Ktx">
      <Version>1.8.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Jvm">
      <Version>1.3.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference">
      <Version>1.2.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Core">
      <Version>121.1.1.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Dagger">
      <Version>2.47.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement">
      <Version>118.2.0.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk7" Version="1.9.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8" Version="1.9.20" />
</ItemGroup>


<ItemGroup>
   <GoogleServicesJson Update="google-services.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </GoogleServicesJson>
</ItemGroup>
```

In the google-services.json file, the package_name match the applicationId. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to call `FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);` in `MainActivity.OnCreate` just before the `LoadApplication(..)` .

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not?